# Setting up an embedded object in a schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Which way would be the correct? And what's the difference?

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    "name": {type: String, unique: true },
    "password": String,
    "tasks": [
        new Schema({
            "name": String,
            "importance": String,
            "completed": Boolean
        })
    ]
})


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    "name": {type: String, unique: true },
    "password": String,
    "tasks":[{//push objects in the array}]
})
```

Would the Schema add an _id to the tasks if i did it the first way too?

Answer (score 0):

[Subdocuments docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childSchema]
})
```

Alternate syntax:

```
var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [{ name: 'string' }]
})
```

These are equivalent. The advantage of the first one is that you can access your schema instance later (by saving it to a variable).

In your case, in the first option, you don't need `new Schema()`, it's implicit.

You can set [_id:false](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) in the schema options if you don't want an id to be generated automatically.